# readarray blocks with input from process

Tags: bash, io-redirection

It seems `readarray` blocks and does not return when the input is redirected from a process using `<`, but it works when input is coming from a pipe `|`.

This works:

```
$ (printf "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n") | (readarray -t ARR ; echo "${ARR[1]}")
line 2
```

This does not return and needs to be killed

```
$ readarray -t ARR <(printf "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n"); echo "${ARR[1]}"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Process substitution outputs a filename and readarray doesn't read from files.  You have to redirect the file into it like:

```
readarray -t ARR < <(printf "line 1\nline 2\nline 3\n"); echo "${ARR[1]}"
```

---

```
$ echo <(echo hello)
/dev/fd/63
$ cat <(echo hello)
hello
```

Comment: What's interesting that it doesn't throw an error for the extra argument the process substitution produces. Neither does it seem to use it, even if it's a valid variable name.